# match method parameters including strings

Tags: regex

I have the expression `(method|function)\((*SKIP)(*F)|[^\n,\s=\)]+?(?=,|\))` 
that matches the parameters of a method called 'method' or 'function'. For example:

```
method(param1, param2, arg3=param3m, "stringParam")
//matches ["param1", "param2", "param3", "\"stringParam\""]
```

but I have the problem that if someone were to try and input a string with one of the delimiting characters, `\s` or `=` it would do the following:

```
method("Hello, world!")
//matches ["\"Hello", "world!\""]
```

I also have the expression `"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"` that matches strings even with escaped quotes. 
What I'm trying to do is to somehow add that to the first expression so it matches strings as wellץ

Comment: Please add the tag language/tool you're using to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this regex, and it supports both type of quotes `'`, `"`:

```regex
(?:(["'])(?:(?<!\\)\\(?:\\\\)*\1|(?!\1).)*?\1|[^,\s=("']*)(?=[,\)])
```

```
(?:                                 non-capturing group
    (["'])                          any type of quote, and put it in group 1
    (?:                             non-capturing group
        (?<!\\)\\(?:\\\\)*\1        escaped quotes(\", \\\" etc)
        |                           or
        (?!\1).                     any character but not the quote that captured
    )*?                             end of group, with any occurances, as few as possible
    \1                              end quote
    |                               or
    [^,\s=("']*                     none delimeter characters or quotes
)                                   end of group
(?=[,\)])                           positive lookahead, must followed by a comma or right parenthesis
```

Check the [test cases](https://regex101.com/r/wjghKt/1/)

Comment: That was really good, but it was matching things like "text)", matched all parentheses regardless of if they had the method names, so it was also matching stuff like (x), and there was a missing \s* but here's what I'm going to try and use `(?:\G(?!\A)|method|function).*?\K(?:(["'])(?:(?<!\\)\\(?:\\\\)*\1|(?!\1).)*?\1|[^,\s=("']+)\s*(?=[,\)])`

Comment: I think as long as in a string closure, whatever the content inside doesn't matter, right?

Comment: I meant that it matched too much. Because your expression only checked for a closing parenthesis, if a user were to try to type `x = 5/(2+1)` then the `2+1` would be picked up and registered as a method parameter. Btw this is for a compiler :p

Comment: @KJBuilds Ah I see what you mean now, you can try the combination like [this one](https://regex101.com/r/aUb7kG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match the part between double quotes as a whole using your expression, you can use an alternation to match either from an opening till closing double quote OR match what is listed in the character class.

Note that you can omit the `\n` from the character class as `\s` also matching a newline, you don't have to escape the `\)` inside it and the lookahead at the end can be shortened using a character class as well `?=[,)])`

```
\b(?:method|function)\((*SKIP)(*F)|(?:"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|[^,\s=)]+)(?=[,)])
```

The pattern matches

- `\b(?:method|function)\(` A word boundary to prevent a partial match, then match either `method` or `function`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` SKIP FAIL backtracking control verbs, do no make this part of the match
- `|` Or
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"` Match from `"..."` also matching escape characters
  - `|` Or
  - `[^,\s=)]+` Match 1+ times any char except what is lister in the character class
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?=[,)])` Positive lookahead, assert `,` or `)` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ITG1Cq/1)

If you also want to use the pattern for single quotes:

```
\b(?:method|function)\((*SKIP)(*F)|(?:"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'|[^,\s=)]+)(?=[,)])
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QeYAWK/1)